# Evaluate an Integral with second part of FTC

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate the integral $\int_{1}^{3} (x^2 + 2x - 4)dx$

My approach to solving this problem was to find the anti-derivative of the integral, $F(x)$, and then evaluate for $F'(x)$ $\rightarrow$ $F'(x) = F(b) - F(a)$.

Anti-derivative is:

$$\frac{3x^3}{3} + x^2 - 4x $$

Evaluate for $F'(x)$:

$$F'(x) = \bigg(\frac{3(3)^3}{3} + 3^2 - 4(3)\bigg) - \bigg(\frac{3(1)^3}{3} + 1^2 - 4(1)\bigg)   
= 27 + 9 - 12 - (1 - 1 - 4) = 26$$

The textbook answer is $\frac{26}{3}$. I am not sure what the missing gap in my knowledge is that I am missing a 3 in the denominator. Any guidance in the right direction would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo, antiderivative should be
$$
1/3x^3 + x^2 - 4x
$$

Comment: It wasn't a typo. That's what I thought the antiderivative is. If it is wrong, why is it wrong?

Comment: @EvanKim What's the derivative of $1/3x^3$? What's the derivative of $\frac{3x^3}3$?

Comment: hmm. I got the derivative of $\frac{1}{3x^3} = -x^{-3}$ and derivative of $\frac{3x^3}{3} = 3x^2$....neither of which are $x^2$

Comment: No no no, $1/3x^3$ means $(1/3)x^3$, not $1/(3x^3)$.

Comment: oh okay. I get $\frac{1}{3x^3}$ now after I use the product rule.

Comment: Clearly, I need to brush up on finding anti-derivatives more before I attempt to use them to evaluate integrals, thanks

Comment: no need to, and mark the answer as correct